# Set the state, clicking the button

Tags: reactjs

I want to set the state clicking the submit button but without using the `<form>` tag, just an input and a button.
My code looks like this:

```js
function Test() {
const [name, setName] = React.useState('John');

    function inputChange(e) {
        let val = e.target.value;
        setName(val)
    }

    function submitFun() {
        //here i want to setName() like "setName(val)", but the variable VAL has  local scope in inputChange()
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>name: {name}</h1>
            <input onChange={inputChange} placeholder='name'/>
            <button onClick={submitFun}>SUBMIT</button>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Now, setName sets the value in that moment when i type in the input. How implement my idea to setName only after i will click on the button?

Comment: what is stopping you from creating a second state variable that is set from the first on submit?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ref` to get value of `<input/>`, more see [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Here, I use `useRef` to create a `ref` object and pass it to `<input/>` (`ref = {inputRef}`).

Then I can use`inputRef.current.value` to get the value of `<input/>`.

```js
function Test() {
    const [name, setName] = React.useState('John');
    
    const inputRef = React.useRef();

    function submitFun() {
        setName(inputRef.current.value)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>name: {name}</h1>
            <input placeholder='name' ref={inputRef} />
            <button onClick={submitFun}>SUBMIT</button>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: in this case i will get the next error: `A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type undefined to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component`

Comment: @AskMen **uncontrolled input of type undefined to be controlled.** is not error its Warning

Comment: @Jay Vaghasiya, correct, but anyway we don't avoid this.

Comment: @AskMen Yes you can pass value in useRef : **React.useRef('John')**

Comment: @AskMen You may set the value of input to undefine to get this warning.

Answer (score 0):

@Agney, you was right;

```js
function Test() {
    const [name, setName] = React.useState('');
    const [btn, setBtn] = React.useState('');


    function inputChange(e) {
        let val = e.target.value;
        setName(val)
    }

    function submitFun() {
        setBtn(name)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>name: {btn}</h1>
            <input value={name} onChange={inputChange} placeholder='name' />
            <button onClick={submitFun}>SUBMIT</button>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Test/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```